# How do I disable a gridView cell through onclick?

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview

I am struggling to get a clicked button in a grid view to be disabled. Here is my code; I am using a custom grid adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView gridView;

    private final String[] items = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
            "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
            "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);

        CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, items);

        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        (CharSequence) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
        button.setText(items[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the letter of the pushed button
     */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the position in the gridview
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you want the button to be disabled?  after the button is clicked? or after the grid list item is clicked?

Comment: after the button is clicked, just not sure how to do it in the grid list format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                // grid list item was clicked, find the button
                Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
                // turn button off
                button.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    (CharSequence) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```